# Google Cloud Run unauthorized when pushing docker image from docker hub

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to push a docker image from hub.docker.com to google cloud run but i will always get the unauthorized error before it completes the task.

My steps are (in the google cloud shell):

```
docker pull tzahi12345/youtubedl-material

docker tag tzahi12345/youtubedl-material gcr.io/PROJECTID/ytt

docker push gcr.io/PROJECTID/ytt
```

Following error message occurs:

> unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this
> operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your
> request, follow the steps in:
> https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

I've read through all stackoverflow questions, watched youtube tutorials, but can't get it to work. I looked for the IAM credentials, and

> service-PROJECT-NUMBER@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com

has access to my project.

I created a docker login, and tried (in the cloud shell)

```
docker login
```

But also without success. I still get the unauthorized error.

I'm trying to recreate these steps without success:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehZGqrBFx5Q

When I click "Create Service" in the console and create a test container, everything works fine.

Comment: Is the docker push failing or the Cloud Run deploy failing? Those are two separate steps that need different permissions.

Comment: Well, the error occurs when i type docker push gcr.io/PROJECTID/ytt, so I'm not sure if its the push or the deploy.. i just get the error message

Comment: That's the push. Did you follow the instructions linked from the error message? Which approach did you go with (if you're unsure which to use, you probably want the cloud credential helper)